# Cannot start Vagrant (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, permission-denied

In installed Vagrant via

```
> sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

But when I tried to start vagrant with any parameter (e.g vagrant init ), I got always following error:

> bash: /usr/bin/vagrant: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: Permission
>   denied

What could be wrong ? Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: The version of Vagrant in the 16.04 repo should be using a side install of ruby and not the system one. Did you try or do something unusual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't install Vagrant from repository but download the last stable version from [Download Vagrant page](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).

Download [Vagrant Debian package 64-bit](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.4/vagrant_1.9.4_x86_64.deb?_ga=2.18612153.1855174759.1494018583-562294755.1494018582) or [32-bit](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.4/vagrant_1.9.4_i686.deb?_ga=2.49012646.1855174759.1494018583-562294755.1494018582) , according your architecture, then install that.